# If the meta site is for the entire family of sites, shouldn't the name/logo be changed?

Tags: discussion, logo

It's a little confusing that the logo says "meta stackoverflow" but the site serves as a discussion site for StackOverflow, ServerFault, and SuperUser.  Shouldn't this site get a name and logo that reflects the true intent or, at least, doesn't obscure it.

One possibility: metatalk.com, which seems to be availble.

If the suggestion to change the name/logo gets some traction maybe we can have a poll question on the new name.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: UserVoice?  just kidding.  I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: I agree. The theme and logo were created a bit hastily, and while the theme has received a few tweaks, the logo has remained the same since launch. (Not that I would object to a few *more* tweaks, namely some color, but that's a different discussion)

Comment: I suggest **Meta StackExchange** with domain `meta.stackexchange.com`. Is't StackExchange the name of the whole group?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's from when the engine was called **stackoverflow engine** (instead of stackexchange)

But yeah, I suppose it could be changed now

Comment: I thought the original intent was to provide a place to discuss SO, but the obvious extension was to make it cover all three sites rather than have a separate meta site for each one.